# bash string, separated by spaces, to array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I want to take a value read in and separate it from its spaces, then do stuff depending on the parts of the array. More exactly, if statement on the first (if false skip rest) 3 element will be changed from a word to a number using another program (a look up database) the 4th and last will check if there is a non-number or number above 64, if there isn't then it will combine it all back together (which I know how to do) then continue on. I have been working on this for over 3 hours now across multiple websites from Google.

```
vzybilly@vzybilly-laptop:~/Desktop$ cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "cmd: " IN

#OIFS=$IFS
#IFS=';'
#arr2=$IN

#a=$(echo $IN | tr " " "\n")
a=$(echo "$IN")
for i in $(seq 0 $((4 - 1))); do
    echo "a[$i] = \"${a[$i]}\""
done

#IFS=$OIFS

exit 0
vzybilly@vzybilly-laptop:~/Desktop$ ./test.sh
cmd: cmd pers item num
a[0] = "cmd pers item num"
a[1] = ""
a[2] = ""
a[3] = ""
```

What I want:

```
vzybilly@vzybilly-laptop:~/Desktop$ ./test.sh
cmd: cmd pers item num
a[0] = "cmd"
a[1] = "pers"
a[2] = "item"
a[3] = "num"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
a=$(echo "$IN")
```

use

```
a=($IN)
```

Comment: nope: `vzybilly@vzybilly-laptop:~/Desktop$ ./test.sh
cmd: cmd pers item num
./test.sh: line 9: cmd: command not found
a[0] = ""
a[1] = ""
a[2] = ""
a[3] = ""`

Comment: Did you by any chance write `a=$($IN)` instead of `a=($IN)`? My command should not be executing anything; and `$()` executes stuff.